# Is it safe to have the same item appearing twice in a ListView backed by a CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have a requirement to display a list of items from a database query. Some of the items need to be displayed twice; once at the top of the list if a specific flag is set, which is the primary sort criteria, and again in their natural position in the list according to the secondary/default sort criteria.

I have my database query correctly returning multiple rows for the relevant items. The rows differ only by the special flag, and the result appears exactly as I expect.

My question: is it safe, from the point of view of the CursorAdapter or the ListView, to have multiple rows with the same `_id`? Or is there a requirement somewhere that the `_id` field be unique in a given result set?

It seems to be working just fine, but I don't know if I'm just lucky.

Comment: If you're nervous about it, you could always wrap one `Cursor` in a `CursorWrapper` that looks for requests for the `_id` column and maps it into a unique number space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer...sorta.

The slightly longer but still quick answer...so long as you aren't using a `ListViews` choice mode...you'll be fine.

`CursorAdapters` derive their id for a given item based on the "_id" column. AFAIK, this is pretty much only used when determining which item is checked or activated. The whole checked or activation state only become a relevant concern when you enable one of the choice modes. In fact, not having a unique id returned with `getItemId()` for any adapter will cause the following same problem.

Lets say you've set the choice mode to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL. If the user activates both of your dupe row id items; then rotates the device, they will find that only 1 item has been restored to an activated state instead of both.

Side note, this may or may not affect the selected state too. Quickly glossing over the source code looks like that even though it tracks both a selected item via id and position...it seems to only use the position number to determine which view to show selected. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I'm not using choice mode or item selection/activation, so I think I'm safe. Thanks.